# How to process login with spring security core and grails

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I have integrated spring security core in my grails project and then s2-quickstart too.

So I got all the basic gsps, domain controllers also.

So I have one user with id = 'me' and password (encoded) = 'password' inside the database with role = 'ROLE_ADMIN'.

Now I am confuse with the api classes that they have. I need to show the login page on the start of my project and if user enters the correct id password then it should redirect to dashboard page. So for that I have written following piece of code :

```
UrlMapping.groovy
=================
"/"(controller:"login", action:"auth")

LoginController.groovy
======================
class LoginController {
def authenticationTrustResolver
def springSecurityService

def index = {
       redirect(action: 'auth', params: params)
}
def auth = {
       //Checking Licensing stuff
       ....
       ....

}
def signIn = {
        if ( params.username == null )
            redirect(action: 'login')
        def config = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
        if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
            def targetUri = "/dashboard/loadDashboard"
            redirect(uri: targetUri)
    }
        else
        {
             println params.username
             println params.password

             //Don't know which class I should use here
        }
}

auth.gsp inside (login directory)
=================================
<form action='login/signIn' method='POST' id='loginForm' class='cssform' autocomplete='off'>
<label for='username'>Login ID</label>
                    <input type='text' class='text_' name='j_username' id='username' />
<label for='password'>Password</label>
                    <input type='password' class='text_' name='j_password' id='password' />
<input type='submit' value='Login' />
```

So I don't know how should I pass the username and password to which class inside else part of signIn method of LoginController.

Any help would be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

spring-security does all for you.

Just route your users to the dashboard

```
    UrlMapping.groovy
=================
"/"(controller:"dashboard", action:"indexorwhatever")
```

and annotate with the **@Secured** annotation the DashboardController